# правильность построения фраз в поэзии

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли  составлена фраза в строке из стихотворения:
"Верою служить Отец Тебе..."
Речь идет о строках из псалма (обращение к Богу).

Answer (score 1):

Обычный порядок слов: Служить тебе верою, Отец.

Но здесь использована **инверсия**, то есть изменение порядка слов. Цель инверсии ― л**огическое выделение слова ударением**: ВЕрою служить Отец Тебе. Этот прием применяется как в стихах, так и в прозе.

Позиция обращения свободная, она может меняться.

Comment: Почему обращение Отец не выделено запятыми?

Comment: По правилам нужны запятые, только в богословских текстах они не всегда соблюдаются, поэтому я не стала исправлять. Например: Я вновь иду к Тебе, Отец в молитве.